# Reassigning a return variable to a function in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out why I am getting a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax " the variable title is highlighted red

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def getTitle(url):
    try:
    html=urlopen(url)
    except HTTPError as e:
    return None
    try:
    bsObj=BeautifulSoup(html.read())
    title=bsObj.body.h1
    except AttributeError as e:
    return None
    return title
title=getTitle("http://....html")
```

Comment: I believe you need to indent properly what is after the `try` and `except`.

Comment: @MattCremeens: the error message would point elsewhere.

Comment: However, without the **full** error message we can't really help and only speculate as to what might be wrong.

Comment: You are also mixing tabs and spaces (and with a tab-size of 8 spaces you'd have the right indentation, while Stack Overflow displays tabs at 4 spaces instead). Don't do this; uses *spaces only* for indentation (your editor can translate tabs to spaces *for you*). Since you are using Python 3, that is most probably the source of your error here; Python 3 explicitly disallows mixing of indentation styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is very sensitive to whitespace, indentation, in order to keep your code looking clean. From what I can see, you need to intent your try/except statements:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def getTitle(url):
    try:
        html=urlopen(url)
    except HTTPError as e:
        return None
    try:
        bsObj=BeautifulSoup(html.read())
        title=bsObj.body.h1
    except AttributeError as e:
        return None
    return title
title=getTitle("http://....html")
```

That should be it, do say if further errors occur.

Comment: The OP is mixing tabs and spaces. With tabs set to 8 spaces (which is what Python uses), the indentation is *entirely correct*.

Comment: I fixed the indentation as per your suggestion and it worked . thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help. please accept as answer if so. Cheers